# Accessing website through a private address

Tags: android, netbeans, ip, wifi, private

I created java web Application and deployed it at glassfish server.
I am running my website server using android phone hotspot. Any other client machine is unable to access it as it provides me with a private address eg. 192.168.43.5
PS: Complete URL is something like this:
192.168.43.5:44372/Name Of Website
Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Could you post some source code?

Comment: deploy your application on some free public domain , your local machine is not having a valid domain so it cant host any application for the internet

Answer (score 2):

deploy your web application on some free website hosting site like [Jelastic](http://www.jelastic.com)
and use url given by them.

Comment: @ Ajit :I tried deploying a zip file of my NetBeans project on  Jelastic  but it didnt provide me a url a;though it worked fine with sample project available on Jelastic.Could U provide me with some other solution and also i wanted to ask does my project's database connectivity with mysql and glassfish server would effect deploying  it on a public domain?

Comment: In jelastic i added a environment selecting glass fish and  mysql 
and deployed my netbeans project's zip file to that environmnet.
but when i m accessing the url i get glass fish resource not availabl error

Do i need to make some other configurations?

Comment: yes when you create your account on jelastic, while creating a environment they will provide u a unique env id you can change it for your convenience then you have to deploy a war file to that env(on the one which you already created). then your url will be something like  http://environment_name.jelastic.dogado.eu/Your_Project_Name